# Vue component in GrapesJS modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, custom-component, grapesjs

Is there any possibility to use Vue components inside GrapesJS modal? I'd like to display some Vue form in modal, where users can pick some options and - after submitting the form - display some result as static HTML in GrapesJS. This is what I've written so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-lumiere-ujxub

So, on custom component drop, modal is displayed (onActive function). In its content I'd like to put my Vue component. After user pick some options and submit form, I'd like to render (onRender) some static HTML as output (with content chosen by user in form).

If this is not possible do you have any suggestions about another approach with Vue + GrapesJS?

Thanks for all answers :)